# Using PrintDocument to print multiple pages

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I'm trying to print invoices. Invoices should be able to be printed on multiple pages, but that's where the problem kicks in. I can perfectly print an invoice on a single page, but as soon as the invoice doesn't fit on a single page, the printjob just quits on the first page.

Here's the code I'm using. 'artikelen' is a list of articles (List). I have read several similar examples, and I'm fairly sure I'm missing something here.

(Edited: some unneccesary code deleted)

```
public void PrintA4Factuur()
    {
        p = new PrintDocument();
        p.PrintPage +=
            new PrintPageEventHandler(printPage);
        printPreviewDialog.Document = p;
        printPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
    }

void printPage(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
    {
Graphics g = e1.Graphics;
int yPos = 320;
float pageHeight = e1.MarginBounds.Height;
int artikelPosition = 0;
while (yPos + 100 < pageHeight
            && artikelPosition < this.artikelen.Count)
        {
            // Do stuff with articles (printing details in different rectangles

            artikelPosition += 1;
            yPos += 20;
        }

        if (artikelPosition < this.artikelen.Count)
        {
            e1.HasMorePages = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e1.HasMorePages = false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your code to do the opposite: if it prints more than one page, it continues to print into infinity.

Try moving your index position variable outside of the `PrintPage` event, because setting it back to zero just sets it to the beginning again:

```
int artikelPosition = 0;
```

Reset it when you start the printing:

```
public void PrintA4Factuur()
{
  artikelPosition = 0

  p = new PrintDocument();
  p.PrintPage += printPage;
  printPreviewDialog.Document = p;
  printPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then comment it out in your PrintPage routine:

```
void printPage(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
{
  Graphics g = e1.Graphics;
  int yPos = 320;
  float pageHeight = e1.MarginBounds.Height;

  // int artikelPosition = 0;

  // continue with code
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. This is a very good moment to slap myself. Thanks a lot! To recap, the printPage() method is called for every page and not for every print job, right? That would explain my error.

Comment: @StefanM Exactly.  That's why keeping yPos in the `printPage` method works, since that is the starting point for printing your lines.

Answer (score 5):

Well, Lars pointed out the problem with resetting `artikelPosition` to zero at the start of each page, but there are a few other problems with this code.

You should always use `e1.MarginBounds`
for coordinates, as margins can be changed by the user and `p.DefaultPageSettings` will not include that.

Use font metrics like `GetHeight(yourDeviceGraphPort)`, don't hard-code line heights.

Always use `float`s for coordinates, do not convert between `int`s.

Fonts are non-managed resources, you must `Dispose` them when you are done with them. It is inefficient to create and dispose fonts repeatedly in a loop; construct it before calling `PrintDocument.Print()` and dispose it after all pages have printed.

There is also a Black SolidBrush already defined in `System.Drawing`.