# printing more pages in printdocument in C#

Tags: c#, printing

I want to print multiple image when print items are increasing. I used to print item by using 
ex.

```
graphic.DrawString("Name of the client/organization", new Font("Courier New", 11, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 40, startY + 70);
graphic.DrawString(": " + NameofClient.Text, new Font("Courier New", 11), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 370, startY + 70);
```

and I try with the   `e.HasMorePages = true` but it count infinity when printing.

I want to know what is the better way to print multiple page.

Here I add the sample print image of document. I want to add more pages when menu items increase (in rectangle area in image)

[image: img]

Comment: surely there is some looping code involved in this? Read the answer to this [other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231860/using-printdocument-to-print-multiple-pages?rq=1) See if it helps.

Comment: @charles no, not looping code involve this, here all the items(see the image ) just print string using graphic.drawsting. i want only if menu items increase jump in to the second page.